Remapping Caps key to Esc key in Hyprland (Arch) from Colemak layout
I use the Colemak layout where both the backspace and the caps lock keys are mapped to backspace. I would like to remap the key that's Caps lock in querty to be the escape key, but can't figure out how to do it.
Using wev, I know that the code of that key is 66.
The Hyprland wiki explains how to replace caps with esc using kb_options, but this doesn't work for me since I don't have that key set to caps in my layout.
Anyone have advice for the cleanest way to do this?
